# Azure DevOps Pipelines Azure PowerShell task: The variable '$PSEdition' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

Receiving an error in the Azure DevOps Pipelines Azure PowerShell task:

```
##[error]The variable '$PSEdition' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
```

The latest AzureRM modules were just installed (6.11.0 at the time of this post).

Answer (score 1):

The AzureRM 6.11.0 module is looking for the $PSVersionTable.PSEdition property which is available in PowerShell 5.1 and greater. Download and install from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616